# Converting month name to month number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, select

I have a column (says Period_name ) that accepts varchar value. Inside the column, I have inputs like*Jan-19, Feb-19, etc*. I need an SQL instruction whenever left of Period_name comes like Jan, Feb then it should convert into corresponding month number.
For example

Input

```
Period_name
Jan-19
Feb-19
```

Output

```
Period name 
01
02
```

The SQL query condition is as follows:

```
Case 
When Left(period_name,3) in{'Jan','Feb'} Then Month(Left(period_name,3))
END
```

Thanks :)

Comment: can you give us more information.

Period_name value is type varchar (What Type do you use)

and the return in which you will use it (filter group or only visualize)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another option is to `try_convert()` into a `date`

Note: the format() is optional

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Period_Name] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Jan-19')
,('Feb-19')

Select * 
      ,NewVal = format(try_convert(date,'01-'+Period_Name),'MM')
 from @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Period_Name NewVal
Jan-19      01
Feb-19      02
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT shortmonths
FROM sys.syslanguages
WHERE langid = 0
```

Returns

```
Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec
```

So another option would be to do a substring look up on that...

```
SELECT 1 + NULLIF(CHARINDEX(LEFT(y.period_name,3), l.shortmonths),0)/4
FROM dbo.YourTable y
CROSS JOIN sys.syslanguages l 
WHERE l.langid = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use a case expression:

```
case left(period_name, 3)
    when 'Jan' then 1
    when 'Feb' then 2
    when 'Mar' then 3
    ...
    when 'Dec' then 12
end month_number
```

But better yet, you can take advantage of SQL Server's date parsing flexibilty. Something like `'01-Jan-19'` should be recognized as a date, so this should work:

```
month(cast('01-' + period_name as date)) month_number
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cbf0d56c6f1e64385b91f9a766e99c15)**:

```
select period_name, month(cast('01-' + period_name as date)) month_number
from (values ('Jan-19'), ('Feb-19')) t(period_name)

GO
```

```
period_name | month_number
:---------- | -----------:
Jan-19      |            1
Feb-19      |            2
```

Comment: thanks GMB, let me know whether there is any other ways to do it without using much case statement

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods available one of that is as shown below. The logic is to convert the `Period_Name` into a date and use the [SQL Server DATEPART() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datepart.asp).

You can use the [TRY_CAST (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to handle the error when the `part_name` value is not in the expected format. It will return `null` in that case.

```
SELECT DATEPART(MM,  + '01-' + 'Jan-19') as MonthNumber

Declare @YourTable Table ([Period_Name] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Jan-19')
,('Feb-19')

SELECT DATEPART(MM,  + Try_cast('01-' + Period_Name as Date)) as MonthNumber
FROM @YourTable
```

Here is the live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d761502ce1d6dfae5e94f507e92d8fcc) demo.

To get the number in double-digit you can try the following query. Note, in this case, you need to convert the number as a string.

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(MM,  + '01-' + Period_Name)  AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) as MonthNumber
FROM @YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functions [`convert()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) like this:

```
select format(convert(date, replace(Period_name, '-', ' 01 '), 1), 'MM-yy') result
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0b16b91c9830ba886d6e59545c25fa7e)
Results:

```
> | result |
> | :----- |
> | 01-19  |
> | 02-19  |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datepart()` :

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONCAT('00', DATEPART(MONTH, CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT('01-', period_name)))), 2);
```

If you don't want `0`s then only `datepart()` would find :

```
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT('01-', period_name)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST('01-'+Column_Name AS DATE),1),2) ,*
FROM Table_Name
```

This Code Works for your Case.
   1st we Should convert our varchar Column into date data type by concating Default date as 01 and then we should use convert function to return for your data type.

Answer (score 0):

A simply approach:

```
select right(t.period_name, 2) year, m.period, m.name
from
(select '01' period, 'Jan' name
  union
  select '02', 'Feb'
   ...
  union
  select '12', 'Dec') m
inner join table1 t
   on Left(t.period_name,3) = m.name
order by right(t.period_name, 2), m.period
```

Return:

```
year -- period -- name
19 ----- 01 -------- Jan
19 ----- 02 -------- Feb
19 ----- 03 -------- Mar
 ...
19 ----- 12 -------- Dec
20 ----- 01 -------- Jan
20 ----- 02 -------- Feb
20 ----- 03 -------- Mar
 ...
20 ----- 12 -------- Dec
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

PARSE/TRY_PARSE:

```
select *, 
month(try_parse(v.val as date)), 
month(try_parse(concat(left(v.val+'-', charindex('-', v.val+'-')), '01') as date))
from 
(
values('Jan-19'),('Feb-20'),('Mar-21'),('Apr-03'),('May-18'),('Jun-99'),('Jul-85'),
('Aug-15'), ('Sep-16'),('Oct-'),('Nov'), ('Dec-11')
) as v(val);
```